# Azure/PowerShell : How do I query disk state? (Azure Managed Disks)

Tags: azure, powershell

In the Azure portal, under the Disks  (Managed Disks) blade, there is a column heading called "Disk State"

This is showing as **Attached** or **Unattached.**

I want to run a script to show me all the Unattached disks in my subscription so that I can delete them.

Running the cmdlet

```
get-azurermdisk
```

this gives me all the disks, but how do I get the parameter showing disk state?

`Get-member` shows a bunch of properties but not the disk state.

```
TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.Models.PSDiskList
Name               MemberType Definition
----               ---------- ----------
Equals             Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode        Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType            Method     type GetType()
ToPSDisk           Method     Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.Models.PSDisk ToPSDisk()
ToString           Method     string ToString()
Validate           Method     void Validate()
CreationData       Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.CreationData CreationData {get;set;}
DiskSizeGB         Property   System.Nullable[int] DiskSizeGB {get;set;}
EncryptionSettings Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.EncryptionSettings EncryptionSettings {get;set;}
Id                 Property   string Id {get;}
Location           Property   string Location {get;set;}
ManagedBy          Property   string ManagedBy {get;}
Name               Property   string Name {get;}
OsType             Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.OperatingSystemTypes] OsType {get;set;}
ProvisioningState  Property   string ProvisioningState {get;}
ResourceGroupName  Property   string ResourceGroupName {get;}
Sku                Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.DiskSku Sku {get;set;}
Tags               Property   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string,string] Tags {get;set;}
TimeCreated        Property   System.Nullable[datetime] TimeCreated {get;}
Type               Property   string Type {get;}
Zones              Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[string] Zones {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks unattached disks have the ManagedBy property of Get-AzureRmDisk set to $null

This means that

```
Get-AzureRmDisk | Where-Object ManagedBy -ne $null
```

Should show you all **attached** disks and

```
Get-AzureRmDisk | Where-Object ManagedBy -eq $null
```

Should show you all **unattached** disks

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Get-AzureRmDisk | Where-Object DiskState -eq "Unattached"
```

[image: PowerShell image showing results of Get-AzureRmDisk | Get-Member]